# Request from NodeJs To PHP

Tags: php, linux, node.js

I have simple NodeJs WebSockets Server, and big PHP project. I want to ingrate it. And is it possible to make request from PHP-script to NodeJs-script which runed on one server(whith CentOs 6.4)?

P.S But, can i do this whithout internet, comunicate this scripts using OS tools?

Comment: You may need access to command line. Just run the node command and examine the output.

Comment: See this question I made: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22304214/route-requests-to-laravel-controller-to-running-websocket-server  You will need to create a web socket _client_ in PHP and connect to the web socket server

Comment: This is not a very good question. It's basically "Can PHP talk to node.js over websockets?" and there are many many answers to this question.

Comment: @pcguru but i think, that i can connect it whithout internet.

Comment: Yeah you can. Localhost works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say yes. The question is extremely vague.
This library might be of help to let your php script communicate with nodejs over websockets.

https://github.com/nicokaiser/php-websocket